# Getting all return values of LOV programmatically

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-adf, managed-bean, lov

I'm currently working on a CRUD application and I have defined a LOV like this:

[image]

My question is how can I get all these return values in for example a ValueChangeListener defined like this:

```
public void onValueChanged(ValueChangeEvent ev){
    BindingContext bctx = BindingContext.getCurrent();
    oracle.binding.BindingContainer bindings = bctx.getCurrentBindingsEntry();
    DCIteratorBinding iterBind = (DCIteratorBinding)bindings.get("MpStavkeulazaView5Iterator");
    System.out.println("Vrijednost je" + ev.getNewValue());
}
```

This code only gives me the value of the list attribute, but I want the other values too.

Any other info please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - using backing bean's value change listener is not ideal for such use case:
Try instead the setter on your Row Impl for the same purpose.

Remember: if you can't test your use case from BC tester, your ADF design is flawed.

Second of all: your LOV can return multiple values:
http://adfbugs.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/returning-multiple-values-from-lov-in.html

Comment: I need to access the values programmatically to calculate a filed in the table. The link you posted shows that it can return multiple values but not how to get them from a bean.

Comment: any ideas regarding my comment?

Answer (score 1):

You can bind row attributes and then get values of this bindings or just get this attributes from iterator. If you going to handle it in `valueChangeListener` you'll have to process updates, before getting this values:

```
public void onValueChanged(ValueChangeEvent ev){
  BindingContainer bindings = BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
  DCIteratorBinding iterBind = (DCIteratorBinding)bindings.get("MpStavkeulazaView5Iterator");
  System.out.println("Vrijednost je" + ev.getNewValue());
  ev.processUpdates(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
  Row row = iterBind.getCurrentRow();
  System.out.println("Proizvod: " + row.getAttribute("Proizvod"));
  System.out.println("Jmjere: " + row.getAttribute("Jmjere"));
}
```

However its may be better to use Transient attribute in your ViewObject and do calculations there?